# Large Gaps Between Almost Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

What is the best lower bound for the longest interval contained in $[1,x]$ free of primes and products of two primes? In other words I am asking for the best lower bounds in a variant of the Westzynthius-Erdos-Rankin problem of finding large gaps between primes, as in [this recent paper.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5029.pdf)

[In this question,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130982/what-is-most-current-greatest-lower-bound-on-gaps-between-p2-almost-primes) it seems like the person was trying to ask a similar question.

Comment: A trivial bound is $\log x/\log\log x.$